# Matching string removal from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, pattern-matching

I am working in SQL Server 2014. I have 2 columns in a table named `Gallery Name` and `Address`. Below is my sample data from this table.

```
Gallery Name           Address
--------------------------------------------------------------
Boltelang              Boltelang street 12, Paris
BERG Contemporary      BERG Contemporary gorge ave, New York
```

Like this, I have a total of 207 records. Now the issue is that the data of column `Gallery Name` is being repeated in address column which I want to remove from address column. So it should be like this in

```
Gallery Name          Adress
--------------------------------------------
Bltelang              street 12, Paris
BERG Contemporary     gorge ave, New York
```

I have no clue which function I can use in SQL Server to achieve this

Comment: [REPLACE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your query is to use `REPLACE` like following.

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME 
SET [Address] = REPLACE([Address], [Gallery Name],'')
```

**Note**: In above query, `REPLACE` will replace all the occurrences of  [Gallery Name] in [Address].

There can be scenario where you need to replace **only the first occurance**, not if it exists somewhere in the middle. In that case you can try like following.

```
 UPDATE T SET  [Address]= 
         LTRIM(STUFF([Address], CHARINDEX([Gallery Name], [Address]), LEN([Gallery Name]), ''))
    from TABLE_NAME T
    WHERE [Address] LIKE [Gallery Name] +'%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for:

```
update t
    set address = stuff(address, 1, len(gallery_name) + 1, '')
    where address like gallery_name + ' %';
```

These cover the examples in your question, where the gallery name is at the beginning of the address followed by a space.  I am very conservative in making such changes.  If you have another pattern, then you can run another update to fix those.

You want to be careful using `REPLACE()`, in case the address repeats the gallery name:

```
New York     New York 10 New York Ave
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's only needed when the "Gallery Name" is at the start of the "Address".

To correct the addresses in the table

```
UPDATE [YourTable]
SET [Address] = LTRIM(REPLACE([Address], [Gallery Name],''))
WHERE [Address] LIKE CONCAT([Gallery Name],'%')
```